# how to name the elements of a list on the fly?

Tags: r

I would like to name the elements of a list on the fly with the content of the variable, how should I do?

```
DT <- data.table(A=LETTERS[1:3], B=letters[1:3], C= 1:9)

lapply(unique(DT$A), function(xA){
  RTN <- 
    lapply(unique(DT$B), function(xB){
        output <- DT[A == xA & B == xB]$C
         if(length(output)== 0L) {
         }else{
           c(xA, xB, output)
         }
    }) 
})
```

the result is

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] "A" "a" "1" "4" "7"
[[1]][[2]]
NULL
[[1]][[3]]
NULL
[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
NULL
[[2]][[2]]
[1] "B" "b" "2" "5" "8"
[[2]][[3]]
NULL
```

I would like to make it as following

```
[[A]]
[[A]][[a]]
[1] "A" "a" "1" "4" "7"
[[A]][[b]]
NULL
[[A]][[c]]
NULL
[[B]]
[[B]][[a]]
NULL
[[B]][[B]]
[1] "B" "b" "2" "5" "8"
[[B]][[c]]
NULL
```

Besides, how can I remove the NULL, and make it a complete case matrix? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two solutions:

1) Use sapply and set `USE.NAMES = TRUE`

2) Capture the names before each lapply and set them after.

```
DT <- data.table(A=LETTERS[1:3], B=letters[1:3], C= 1:9)

outer_list_names <- unique(DT$A)
outer_list  <- lapply(unique(DT$A), function(xA){
  RTN_names = unique(DT$B)
  RTN <- 
    lapply(unique(DT$B), function(xB){
        output <- DT[A == xA & B == xB]$C
         if(length(output)== 0L) {
         }else{
           c(xA, xB, output)
         }
    })
  names(RTN) <- RTN_names 
})
names(outer_list) <- outer_list_names
outer_list
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. When I am using `sapply`, whether I use it at inner loop or outer, or both. The result became a matrix not giving the contents, but the summary like " Character,5"

Comment: Try adding the argument `simplify=FALSE`

Comment: many thanks, it works. I should have read help more closely. I neglect the basic part, my bad.

Answer (score 2):

We could create a named vector to name the list

```
A_vec <- setNames(unique(DT$A), unique(DT$A))
B_vec <- setNames(unique(DT$B), unique(DT$B))

lapply(A_vec, function(xA){
     RTN <- lapply(B_vec, function(xB){
     output <- DT[A == xA & B == xB]$C
     if(length(output) >  0L) {
       c(xA, xB, output)
     }
   })
})


#$A
#$A$a
#[1] "A" "a" "1" "4" "7"

#$A$b
#NULL

#$A$c
#NULL


#$B
#$B$a
#NULL

#$B$b
#[1] "B" "b" "2" "5" "8"

#$B$c
#NULL
```

If you want to remove the `NULL` values we could have a `Filter` to remove them

```
lapply(A_vec, function(xA){
     RTN <- lapply(B_vec, function(xB){
     output <- DT[A == xA & B == xB]$C
     if(length(output) >  0L) {
        c(xA, xB, output)
     }
   })
   Filter(Negate(is.null), RTN)
})


#$A
#$A$a
#[1] "A" "a" "1" "4" "7"


#$B
#$B$b
#[1] "B" "b" "2" "5" "8"


#$C
#$C$c
#[1] "C" "c" "3" "6" "9"
```